How can I plumb a clothes washer's outlet and a heat pump dryer's drain into the same standpipe?
A new LG clothes washer (LG WM3400CW) will be installed in place of an existing and older clothes washer; the existing washer will be removed. The new machine's water discharge would fit easily into the same standpipe used by the older machine.
The replacement dryer (LG DLHC5502W) is a heat pump dryer, and also has a water drain. The new dryer will be installed next to the washer.
How might I plumb both water discharge lines into the same standpipe? I'd like the system to accommodate both machines running at the same time.
This California house (wood frame, stucco exterior, and sheetrock inside) was built in 1967. In the early 80s, my father moved the washer and dryer from a previous location upstairs.
While a visually ugly job:

this plumbing and drainage has worked without fault for the last 35 years. The standpipe in the wall is 2" ABS, and the water valves look to me like they were taken out of a shower. All the sheetrock here will be removed and redone properly, with a conventional wall insert with two ¼ turn valves and a drain.
On the other side of the wall is a bathroom. My father was a persistent DIY'er with very good knowledge of how things should be — he knew about vents, for instance — and because it's worked so well for so long (no plugs or clogs or back-ups) I suspect that the standpipe is actually plumbed into the venting; I can see a roof vent (metal, perhaps 2½ inch pipe) above the toilet location in the bathroom. It's been years since I've been under the house — there is a crawlspace, but I'm closing in on 80. I don't remember what can be seen there.
We will know more when the old machine is removed and the sheetrock comes out. That's probably this week or next.

How about some details about the existing drain  and th drain pipes from the washer and dryer.

Oddly enough, I just installed a new LG heat pump dryer last week.
There is a drain adapter/combiner which takes the washer and dryer output hoses and combines them into one outlet.  The part looks similar to this (in this "online store" image, the part is pictured upside-down):

Here's a screenshot of the installation manual indicating how it is used:

The part number for the adapter is LG MCD63147101.

Thanks! This two-into-one (is the picture upside-down?) would do the job, I suspect. There is no mention of this part in the manual, and the part itself is absent. Can you share an LG part number?

I chatted with an LG person through LG's online chat system. This is LG part no. LG MCD63147101, available from LG directly and (cheaper!) from Amazon.

Yep, in the "parts store" picture I stole, it is pictured upside down.  Kind of counter-intuitive. ;)

Thanks for adding the part number.  I have added it to the answer for completeness.
